# How can I create an SVG where elements' position are relative to others?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I would like to create an SVG inside-out, ie, make a text, draw a box around it, do the same with another text, align the boxes, ...

so basically, none of the elements have a predefined dimensions and positions.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg x="50" y="50">
    <rect height="100" width="100" style="fill: #00cc00"/>
      <svg x="50" y="50"> <!-- y is missing the width substract -->
      <text y="8">text</text>
      </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

this first method has a problem, because at some points some X/Y may end up with negative coordinates, making the objects cut.

so I tried with D3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.5"></script>
<script>
body = d3.select('body')
svg = body.append('svg')
text = svg.append('text').text('text')
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('y', 16)
delta = 25
W = parseInt(text.style("width")) + delta + "px"
H = parseInt(text.style("height")) + delta + "px"
X = parseInt(text.attr("x")) - delta / 2
Y = parseInt(text.attr("y")) - delta / 2 - parseInt(text.style('font-size')) / 2

rect = svg.append('rect')
            .attr('width', W)
            .attr('height', H)
            .attr('x', X)
            .attr('y', Y)
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'black')

W = parseInt(rect.attr("width")) + delta + parseInt(rect.attr("x")) + "px"
H = parseInt(rect.attr("height")) + delta  + parseInt(rect.attr("y")) + "px"

svg.attr('height', H)
    .attr('width', W)
</script>
```

which kinda works but the text is not very well centered, and is quite heavy to implement.

Any (lightweight) suggestion - with or without D3 ?

Comment: You probably want to use plain html instead of SVG if you want to layout stuff like this

Comment: but then, how do you draw graphical elements: box, arrows, etc... ?

Comment: show us an image of what you want and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: @Duopixel http://i.imgur.com/pHjcI.png, in an automated way

Answer (score 0):

My style is to use a single <svg> and simpliest setup is:-

1. Use `getbbox()` to define the `<rect>` around each `<text>` (this is the bounding box for each text element)

   Wrap a `<g>`roup tag around each pair of `<rect>` and `<text>`

   Repeat this for the rest of the `<text>` element.

   Use `transform()` on each `<g>` tag, if the first starts at `y = 0`, the second starts at 
   `y = rect_#1_height + offset`, and so on

To access the elements in native Javascript, use something like this:-

> var svgdoc = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0] **«- svg docs**
>   var textArray = svgdoc.document.getElementsByTagName('g')  **«- returns array**
>   textArray[10]  **«- the 10th element**

One of the major headache of SVG is no automatic text-wrap, there are ways around it.